# Show data in text input on select option change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Hey i need help to show data on change select. I need to show that in input field with id "cijena". I think only problem is that is not showing data in input field.

```
<?php 

    include_once '../functions/general_functions.php';
    $con = spajanje();

    if (isset($_POST['ispisCijenaId'])) {
        $cijenaId = $_POST['ispisCijenaId'];
        if(strlen($cijenaId) >0) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM grupa WHERE id_smjer_fk = {$cijenaId}";
            $cijene = upit($con,$sql);
            if (count($cijene>0)) {
                foreach ($cijene as $cijena){
                echo "{$cijena}['id_grupa'], {$cijena}['cijena'] ";
                } 
            } else {
                echo 'Nema aktivnih grupa';
            }   
        }
    } //end isset

?>


<div class="form-group col-xs-4">         
        <label name="cijena">Cijena</label>
        <input id="cijena" class="form-control" type="text" name="cijena" readonly="readonly">
    </div>


function ispisCijena(cijenaId){
            if(cijenaId.length > 0) {
                $.post("ajax/ispisCijena.php", {ispisCijenaId: ""+cijenaId+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#cijena').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: <div class="form-group col-xs-4">         
          <select id="grupa" name="grupa" class="form-control" onchange="ispisCijena(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
              <option value="">Izaberite prvo smjer</option>
          </select>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
{ispisCijenaId: ""+cijenaId+""}
```

to this:

```
{ispisCijenaId: cijenaId}
```

---

and instead of setting value with `.html()` use `.val()`:

```
if(data.length >0) {
   $('#cijena').val(data);
}
```

Comment: I get this error in input field.  <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt-skola\ajax\ispisCijena.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt-skola\ajax\ispisCijena.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />Array['id_grupa'], Array['cijena']

Comment: may be you should use external serverside which currently seems to be on a same page.

Comment: I just need to echo value from db column named "cijena". And i think i made mistakes here in this line.  echo "{$cijena}['id_grupa'], {$cijena}['cijena'] ";